# Adding another language (Vietnamese) to the the latex template

Tags: unicode, utf8

I'm trying to add the language Vietnamese to this [latex template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/latex-mimosis/syptyjpjrzzj)
Here is the picture before I add Vietnamese into the language package. It's still has the bold effect on the text "Introduction".
[image]

However, after adding Vietnamese and compiling with PDFLatex all the style like **bold** and *italic* in the document gone.  [image]

I also compiling with other engines like XELatex and LuaLatex but it only shows error `Package fontspec Error: The font "MinionPro" cannot be found.`
I'm suspecting the utf8 font has many special characters that are really different from English so Latex couldn't recognize and clear all the style. So, I want to know what cause the error and how can I fix this?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please do not include code as pictures, we can not copy and play with it ...

Comment: Hi, Vietnamese here. Generally I'd suggest using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX for languages such as Vietnamese. They are also very fast like pdfLaTeX, and can support Unicode very well, so you don't need to worry about things like this.

Comment: @Mensch Sorry, I can't copy the code here because it's the whole template folder. I just want to add some images to show that things are not working as my expectation.

Comment: you are not even saying which engine you actually use for compiling.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I updated the question

Comment: Also, I've tried XeLatex and LuaLatex as @fractal's suggestion but still doesn't work.

Comment: the class uses ebgaramond as font and that font doesn't support vietnamese and so the fonts revert to computer modern.